# How to rename files on a date base in the shell?

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

I'd like to rename some files that are all in the same directory. The file name pattern used is `Prefix_ddmmyy.tex` with a european date format. For the sake of readability and the ordering I'd like to rename the files in a pattern `Prefix_yymmdd.tex` with a canonical date format.

Anyone ideas how I can do this automatically for a complete directory? My sed and regexp knowledge is not very sharp...

Comment: I always thought that the "American" date format was mmddyy.

Comment: Yes, American is mmddyy, wheread yymmdd (or rather yyyymmdd) is canonical (most notably, unlike other formats, it actually sorts properly.)

Comment: Ok excuse the error. Than I'll take the canonical variant. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for file in Prefix_*.tex ; do
      file_new=`echo "$file" | sed -e 's:\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\([0-9][0-9]\)\(\.tex\):\3\2\1\4:'`
      test "$file" != "$file_new" && mv -f "$file" "$file_new"
    done

Or, if you have a lot of files and/or want to process files recursively, replace:

```
for file in Prefix_*.tex ; do
```

with:

```
find . -name Prefix_*.tex -print | while read file ; do
```

or (non-recursive, GNU):

```
find . -maxtdepth 1 -name Prefix_*.tex -print | while read file ; do
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with any bourne-type shell without external commands:

```
for f in *.tex; do
  _s=.${f##*.} _f=${f%.*} _p=${f%_*}_ 
  _dt=${_f#$_p} _d=${_dt%????} _m=${_dt%??} 
  _y=${_dt#$_m} _m=${_m#??}
  mv -- "$f"  "$_p$_y$_m$_d$_s"
done
```

With *zsh* it would be:

```
 autoload -U zmv
 zmv '(*_)(??)(??)(??)(.tex)' '$1$4$3$2$5'
```

Comment: I understand the solution from Vlad, but can you explain what your script does. I don't understand the binding of the different variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can try "[mmv](http://www.ss64.com/bash/mmv.html)".